# Is it legal to host a free movie website in the US?

Tags: business

I was thinking of starting a website where you can watch free movies. Now I know it's illegal to host movies, but what if my site just embeds a movie from another site who is hosting it? BTW, if it is legal, can I charge users a small fee just to access my site?

Comment: What country are you in? Sealand hopefully.

Comment: The US, btw i've seen other sites like http://putlocker.is that do something like this. They have a message that says "All of the free movies found on this website are hosted on third-party servers that are freely available to watch online for all internet users. Any legal issues regarding the free online movies on this website should be taken up with the actual file hosts themselves, as we're not affiliated with them." Is what they're doing legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad you don't live in Sealand. The *Grokster* case held:

> Producers of technology who promote the ease of infringing on
>   copyrights can be sued for inducing copyright infringement committed
>   by their users.

In other words, no it's not legal in the US.

Saturday night laziness, quotes are from Wikipedia.